# Drawing in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know that you can draw in a view, using CoreGraphics. But it is restricted to the drawRect function.

I was wondering if you could have an app, that has a couple of buttons (UP,DOWN,LEFT,RIGHT). And when the user selects the button it draws a line from the original point in the direction of the button that was just selected by like 20 pixel.

FOR EXAMPLE :

Say the user hits the right button :

```
              Start
                +----------+
```

Then they hit the down button :

```
              Start
                +----------+
                           |
                           |
                           |
                           |
                           +
```

Then they hit the left button

```
                +----------+
                           |
                           |
                           |
                           |
                +----------+
```

Etc,

Can this be done using quartz or do I need to learn something like OpenGL?

Comment: You can use UIBezier Path.

Comment: Why don't you do it in `-drawRect:`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `UIBezierPath` it's pretty easy:

This is a fast, basic example how to draw it

1. UIView subclass let's say `MoveView`, with a public method `-moveToDirection:`
2. View stores directions in an Array
3. Every time when new direction added we call `-setNeedsDisplay` to draw new line

Note: just basic example, sure you need to modify it and implement some restrictions

MoveView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MovieViewDirection) {
    MoveViewDirectionRight,
    MoveViewDirectionLeft,
    MoveViewDirectionUp,
    MoveViewDirectionDown
};

@interface MoveView : UIView

- (void)moveInDirection:(MovieViewDirection)direction;

@end
```

MoveView.m

```
#import "MoveView.h"

static const CGFloat kMoveViewStepDistance = 20.0f;

@interface MoveView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *movingDirections;

@end

@implementation MoveView

#pragma mark - Services

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIBezierPath* bezierPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;        

    CGPoint currentPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));        
//    Start point by default it is a center
    [bezierPath moveToPoint: currentPoint];

    for (NSNumber *direction in self.movingDirections) {
        CGPoint moveToPoint;
        switch (direction.integerValue) {
            case MoveViewDirectionLeft:
                moveToPoint = CGPointMake(currentPoint.x - kMoveViewStepDistance, currentPoint.y);
                break;
            case MoveViewDirectionRight:
                moveToPoint = CGPointMake(currentPoint.x + kMoveViewStepDistance, currentPoint.y);
                break;
            case MoveViewDirectionUp:
                moveToPoint = CGPointMake(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y - kMoveViewStepDistance);
                break;
            case MoveViewDirectionDown:
                moveToPoint = CGPointMake(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y + kMoveViewStepDistance);
                break;                
            default:
                break;
        }
        currentPoint = moveToPoint;
        [bezierPath addLineToPoint: moveToPoint];
    }

    [UIColor.redColor setStroke];
    bezierPath.lineWidth = 1;
    [bezierPath stroke];

}

#pragma mark - Public
- (void)moveInDirection:(MovieViewDirection)direction {
    [self addMoveStepInDirection:direction];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

#pragma mark - Private

- (void)addMoveStepInDirection:(MovieViewDirection)direction {
    NSMutableArray *steps = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.movingDirections];
    [steps addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:direction]];
    self.movingDirections = steps;
}

@end
```

This is what I got:

[image]